# I wrote a function that takes two strings and returns, without doubles, common chars. What's wrong with it?

Tags: c, string, function

I've function that takes two strings and returns, without doubles, the
characters that appear in both strings, in the order they appear in the first
one.
Here's my implementation in C :

```
#include <string.h>
//Remove all char duplicates in string
//Sub function
char *removeAll(char* str,char c, int pos)
{
        int i,j;
        int len = strlen(str);

        for (i = pos+1;i<len;i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == c)
            {
                for (j=i;j<len;j++)
                {
                    str[j] = str[j+1];
                }
                len--;i--;
            }
        }
        return str;
}
//Finds all common chars and concatenate it to one string
//Sub function
char* commonString(char* p1,char* p2)
{
    char* res = "";
    for (int k=0;k<strlen(p1);k++)
    {
        for (int h=0;h<strlen(p2);h++)
        {
            if (p1[k] == p2[h])
            {
                strcat(res,&p1[k]);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;   
}
/* The main function that takes two strings and return, without doubles, the
characters that appear in both strings, in the order they appear in the first
one.*/
char* inter(char* s1,char* s2)
{
    char* new_str,*new_str1;
    int len1 = strlen(s1),len2 = strlen(s2);
    for (int i = 0;i<len1;i++)
    {
        new_str = removeAll(s1, s1[i], i);
        len1 = len1-(len1-strlen(new_str));
        if (strcmp(new_str, s1) != 0) i = 0;
    }
    for (int j = 0;j<len2;j++)
    {
        new_str1 = removeAll(s2, s2[j], j);
        len2 = len2-(len2-strlen(new_str1));
        if (strcmp(new_str1, s2) != 0) j = 0;
    }
    char* res = commonString(new_str, new_str1);
    return res;
}
```

It gives "**FAILURE EXECUTION**"
What's wrong with my code? Can you help fix this?

Examples of I/O:

Example 00

```
> Input: "padinton" && "paqefwtdjetyiytjneytjoeyjnejeyj"
> Output: 
> Return Value: "padinto"
```

Example 01

```
> Input: "ddf6vewg64f" && "gtwthgdwthdwfteewhrtag6h4ffdhsd" 
> Output: 
> Return Value: "df6ewg4"
```

Example 02

```
> Input: "nothing" && "This sentence hides nothing"
> Output: 
> Return Value: "nothig"
```

Comment: where is the *main* function ?

Comment: To be honest this is task from from a specific platform(site). So I just need to write an function. Can you review it?

Comment: Please look at my answer explaining some of your problems starting  by your execution failure, anyway I do not solve all of them because the others are an other question

Comment: Sure, I've already fixed string comparing in my own code.Thanks for that.Now all I need is to fix "common String" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code

> It gives "FAILURE EXECUTION" What's wrong with my code?

In *commonString* you try to modify a literal string which is by definition not modifiable so the behavior is undefined :

> ```
> char* res = "";
> ...
> strcat(res,&p1[k]);
> ```

---

Out of that *removeAll* always return its first argument, so in *inter*

> ```
> new_str = removeAll(s1, s1[i], i);
> ...
> if (new_str != s1) i=0;
> ```

and

> ```
> new_str1 = removeAll(s2, s2[j], j);
> ...
> if (strcmp(new_str1, s2) != 0) j = 0;
> ```

the tests are always true, even doing that you compare pointers and probably you wanting to compare their contents supposing they can be different (but of course they cannot). To compare the content of two string use *strcmp*

Comment: Detail: "a literal string which is by definition not modifiable" is more like, it is undefined behavior to attempt to modify a string literal.  It _might_ work.   IAC, good code does not attempt modification.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are right, I correct. There are lot problems in that code may be it was better for me to not start to look at it ^^